# How to generate random points(x,y,z) given a set of points

Tags: java, math, opengl-es

How to generate random points `(x,y,z)` in java, given a set of points say

`float[] array{ 0.5f,0.0f,0.0f,-0.5f,0.0f,0.0f....};`

where array is in the form `{x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2...}` and points specified array forms the boundary so that I can use these points to generate grid in openglEs2.0

Comment: Just scale down the math by 3.

Comment: I think I’d just make points out of the entire array first and then pick a random one of those. If you don’t want to do this, use a `Random` object, call its `nextInt(array.length / 3)` and multiply the result by 3 to get the start index of your point coordinates.

Comment: When you say the array forms a boundary, do you mean you want a random point within the boundary, not a point that is in the array?

Comment: yes i want random point within the boundary@OleV.V.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem complicated at first when we don’t know the shape of the boundary. My best suggestion is you take a weighted average of the points. I expect that this will give you satisfactory results in all cases, but you need to make your own judgement.

One way to produce a weighted average: Generate as many random double or float numbers as there are points (a third of the length of your float array). `Math.random()` can do that. With four points you may get for example `[ 0.54, 0.74, 0.12, 0.6 ]` (the numbers will have many more decimals, but for the sake of a simple example). Add the numbers (this will yield 2.0 in the example). Divide each number by the sum to obtain `[ 0.27, 0.37, 0.06, 0.3 ]`. Now the sum of the numbers is 1.0, which is what we need: now these numbers are the weights for the weighted average. Scale each point by the corresponding weight and add the scaled points. Now you have your random point within the boundary.

I think I’d generate points from the float array first. I would find point objects more natural to work with, and I think that any bugs can be found more easily, and also I’d be less likely to make any.

I am leaving the actual coding to yourself.